# Segmentation fault in a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, tree, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

Either I've been staring at this code for way too long or I just can't figure this one out.  but when I use an 8000 number text file in descending order; 8000, 7999, ... I get a segmentation fault in the height function.  If someone could take a look I would be so greatful. Thanks.

```
    int BST::height(TreeNode* node)
    {

        int leftSubtree = 0;
        int rightSubtree = 0;
        if (node == NULL)
            return 0;
        else 
        {

            if (node -> getLeft() != NULL)
                leftSubtree = height(node -> getLeft());
            if(node -> getRight() != NULL)      
                rightSubtree = height(node -> getRight());

            if (leftSubtree > rightSubtree)
                return leftSubtree + 1;
            else 
                return rightSubtree + 1;
        }
    }//ends second height
```

Comment: That is nearly 500 lines of code.  What have you been able to learn from using your debugger?  Do you have a call stack to see what happens when the segfault occurs?  Do you know what exactly happens to cause the segfault?  Are you dereferencing a null pointer or recursing too deep?  Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: first of all, i know that its not a debugging site.  I think what happens is that the left subtree recurses too far but I'm not sure why and im not sure where it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sorted list of numbers then you might be storing this in a list (worst case for a tree is O(n) unless it is balanced).

In this case, your recursive routine will be recursing 8000 times with a stack depth of 8000.

I don't know if this is enough to overflow the stack, but in any case you should take a look at your tree at intermediate stages to see if everything is going down the leftmost branch.

Comment: Yea i think youre right.  However, that was the point, to make it all go down the left side of the tree and simulate the worst case running time of the algorithm.  I forgot that the stack probably couldn't handle it so I went with a different direction.